# how to set heading off in jdbc request of Jmeter

Tags: sql, jmeter

**Requirement**:
i need to set heading off in the JDBC Request as i do not wish to see the Column names in the JDBC Response.
So i have added 'set heading off' to the prepared select statement as in the screen shot, but it throws error.

[image: JDBC Request Sampler]

[image: JDBC Response]

How do we fetch only rows from DB without column names in JDBC Sampler of JMeter?

Comment: `set heading off` is **not** a SQL statement, it is a **SQL\*Plus** command and can **only** be used inside `sqlplus`. You need to change the Java code that extracts the header information if you don't want it

Comment: Thanks. So basically there is no way provided for JDBC sampler to do this right?
i will try to see how to get this done by java code although i am a newbie.